# Python - Putting in user input of days and then displaying equivalent years, months and days

Tags: python, calculator

I'm struggling to find an algorithm for the days portion. I'm able to get the years and months down though. Here's my code

```
def main():

    # Prompt the user for an integer that represents a total number of days 
    user_days = int(input("Enter a total number of days: "))

    # constant variables for: years, months, days

    DAYS_IN_YEAR = 365
    DAYS_IN_MONTH = 30

    # Calculate the user's days into equivalent years
    years = (int(user_days // DAYS_IN_YEAR))

    # Calculate the user's days into equivalent months
    months = (int(user_days // DAYS_IN_MONTH))

    # Calculate the user's days into equivalent days
    # days = (int( user_days - DAYS_IN_MONTH ))
    # days = (int( ))

    # give user their results
    print(user_days, "days are equivalent to: ")

    # display the equivalent years
    print("Years: ", years)

    # display the equivalent months
    print("Months: ", months)

    # display the equivalent days
    print("Days: ", days)



main()
```

Comment: Just use remainder i.e. `%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you take your `days` and do `floor div` by 365, gives you years. Then we need the remaining days so we use the days `modulus` 365 and get the remaining days, we take those and do `floor div` by 30, to get our months. then we take those original remaining days and `modulus` 30 to get our days that are left over

```
days = int(input())
years = days // 365
years_r = days % 365
months = years_r // 30
days_r = years_r % 30
```

> ```
> 400
> Years: 1, Months: 1, Days: 5
> 500
> Years: 1, Months: 4, Days: 15
> ```

Comment: I know i fixed it backed to the original, I changed it for clarity, but then realized just to switch it back

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much, it's exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: np bud :) would appreciate if you checked solved hope all goes well and we see you back here soon!

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use for `divmod()`, which does integer division and gives you both the quotient and the remainder:

```
user_days = 762

DAYS_IN_YEAR = 365
DAYS_IN_MONTH = 30

# Calculate number of years and remainder
years, rem = divmod(user_days, DAYS_IN_YEAR)

# Calculate number of months and remainder
months, days = divmod(rem, DAYS_IN_MONTH)

# Display results
print(user_days, "days are equivalent to: ")
print("Years: ", years)
print("Months: ", months)
print("Days: ", days)

# output:
# 762 days are equivalent to: 
# Years:  2
# Months:  1
# Days:  2
```

Comment: Wow! I never heard of divmod, thanks for the helpful response I learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do this without a start date, because months vary (especially on leap years).  I suggest leaving the date math to the standard library.  Get a datetime.datetime for your start date, use your "days" value to construct a datetime.timedelta, add the two together to get an end date, and then compare the day, month and year of the start and end dates.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, in this program I'm just trying to practice the basics of python but in the future i'll try your suggestion to make the program more advanced and accurate.